# Кластеризация индексов PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Узнал, что PostgreSQL в отличии от MS SQL не кластеризует автоматически таблицу относительно первичного ключа или выбранного иного другого ключа в роли кластеризации. Отсюда вопрос, как часто нужно кластеризировать повторно таблицу, можно ли посмотреть когда последний раз таблица кластеризировалась, может есть какая-та статистика как у MS SQL по степени фрагментации индексов? Не обязательно отвечать на все эти вопросы, достаточно скинуть толковую статью где это объясняется, к сожалению не смог найти этих ответов в сети.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как часто нужно кластеризировать повторно таблицу

В большинстве случаев таблицы в postgresql упорядочивают никогда. То есть не делают это. Используется куча (`heap`) и так она и работает, со своими плюсами и минусами.

Попробуйте сперва определиться с вопросом "зачем вы это хотите". Отсортировать таблицу можно очевидно только по одному признаку. Значит возможно будет лучше `index scan` по диапазону именно по этому критерию (и только поискам по диапазонам, для запросов на одну строку это значения не имеет), в лучшем случае ничего не изменится для поиска по другим критериям. А если говорить про изначально индекс-ориентированные таблицы поверх btree - то поиск по вторичным индексам у них будет медленнее. Для неупорядоченного `heap` в postgresql во всех индексах хранится физический адрес строки в датафайле - `TID`. Поэтому поиск по любому индексу даёт сразу нужные адреса в датафайлах.

Индекс-ориентированные таблицы не серебренная пуля, у этого подхода есть как сильные так и свои слабые стороны.

> можно ли посмотреть когда последний раз таблица кластеризировалась

По полю `indisclustered` системного каталога [`pg_index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-index.html) можно узнать, что таблица в принципе когда-то упорядочивалась командой `cluster`. Когда это было - данные не сохраняются.

Насколько разошёлся физический порядок строк с тем что был после сортировки - можно оценить по полю `correlation` в [`pg_stats`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html) представлении. Чем оно меньше 1 - тем более неупорядоченно расположены данные. Однако надо иметь в виду, что это данные статистики, которая собирается автовакуумом (или ручным analyze) по некоторой случайной выборке из таблицы.